# Making a cross-domain XMLHttpRequest from WebView in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is it possible to make a cross-domain XMLHttpRequest from a webview instance in Cocao?

I have a WebView inside a window. I also load some javascript using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: method of the web view. In my test case, I simply create a XMLHttpRequest to a remote host. Unfortunately, nothing is returned back to me. I suspect that I need to configure something in order to allow this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the discussion for stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:?

According to the discussion:

JavaScript execution time is limited to 10 seconds for each top-level entry point. If your script executes for more than 10 seconds, the web view stops executing the script.

I was thinking about it and I wasn't sure if you sent off a request like that if the actual response would be technically part of the scripts execution time.

Is it possible your response is taking longer than 10 seconds?  If it is: that may very well be your problem.

I hope this helps.